# selenium webdriver can't drag and drop fullcalendar events

Tags: selenium-webdriver, fullcalendar

I'm using the selenium webdriver (python) to automate testing of an app that uses the [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) js plugin library.  However, I'm having trouble automating dragging and dropping events to the calendar.

After a lot of experimentation, I can see that the test code below moves the event element to the correct location.  When this action is done by hand on the browser, the calendar square that you are hovering on turns blue and the event, when dropped, is added to the calendar.  This does not happen when the event is moved via automation -- the calendar square does not turn blue, and the event, when dropped, returns to its original position.

How can I get the same drag and drop functionality under automation?

```
    evt = self.sel.find_element_by_css_selector('#evt1')
    cal_square = self.sel.find_element_by_css_selector('td[data-date=\'%s\']' % move_to_date.isoformat())
    ActionChains(self.sel).click_and_hold(evt).move_to_element(cal_square).perform()
    time.sleep(10)
    ActionChains(self.sel).release().perform()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Here's a link to at test case which demonstrates the issue:
https://gist.github.com/jenniferlianne/9353489

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that -- as Micheal pointed out -- after the move, the mouse was reverting back to original element position and doing the release() there.  You can supply the release() function with the element where you want the 'mouse up' to happen.

For whatever reason, this works:

```
    ActionChains(self.sel).click_and_hold(
        evt).move_to_element(cal_square).release(cal_square).perform()
```

While this does not:

```
    ActionChains(self.sel).drag_and_drop(evt, cal_square).perform()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with time while drag and drop. I need some wait after move_to_element and release, but after move_to_element.perform my mouse gets to the coordinates of dragged element and release over there. What can I do with that?

After a while I try this:

```
    parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Parent')]")
    welcome_form = driver.find_element_by_id(link.my_forms["welcome_to_pdf_form"])

    actions.click_and_hold(welcome_form).move_to_element(parent).click().perform()
```

I don't actually know why it works. I thought it will generate click after click and I will get an error but works fine.